# Import button greyed out in Google Sheets menu for unknown reason

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to import a .csv file into my Google Sheet like I've done myriad times. However, occasionally, the `Import` button in the menu is greyed out (see screenshot).

Reloading the document doesn't help. I've looked around for others having the same problem but couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know why this happens and what a solution to this is so that I can upload my data again?

Is there a way to view *logs* or something like that to find out the cause of the greying out?

Update: The button has come back after the umptieth reload. My gut feeling says it's got something to do with unreliable network conditions.

[image]

Comment: It looks that your spreadsheet isn't empty. Try it on a new spreadsheet

Comment: @Ruben It usually works on non-empty spreadsheets too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

From the question:

> Is there a way to view logs or something like that to find out the cause of the greying out?

Google Sheets doesn't keep logs of the opening / loading processes but you could use the web browser developers tools to track it .  One article that might help:

- [Measure Resource Loading Times](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/resource-loading)

Answer (score 0):

This may happen to you because you are viewing a document either:

a) not signed in at all or
b) signed in as a Google user that does not have permissions to edit the document

Check the top right corner of your screen to see what user you are logged in as.